# Ubuntu Second Wan Interface Card

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, routing, linux-networking

I configured 3 network card.
one of them is LAN card and others are Wan network card.

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:00:30:da  
      inet addr:5.x.x.1  Bcast:5.x.x.3  Mask:255.255.255.248
      inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe00:30da/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:4898 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:5410 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:461542 (461.5 KB)  TX bytes:970151 (970.1 KB)

eth1  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr de:8d:6a:0c:af:05  
      inet addr:10.0.0.254  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::dc8d:6aff:fe0c:af05/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:50 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:2950 (2.9 KB)  TX bytes:468 (468.0 B)

eth2  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:00:32:f7  
      inet addr:5.x.x.2  Bcast:5.x.x.3  Mask:255.255.255.248
      inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe00:32f7/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:2619 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:217904 (217.9 KB)  TX bytes:960 (960.0 B)
```

Routing table:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         static.225.150. 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
localnet        *               255.255.255.248 U     0      0        0 eth0
localnet        *               255.255.255.248 U     0      0        0 eth2
10.0.0.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

I can ping or connect from eth0. However, I want to conenct to server via eth2 ip address.
and I can't pinging and ssh via eth2.
eth0 and eth2 ip address use same gateway address. So, these ip address are same subnet.
mac restriction for ip address so, I use two interface card.

What could be doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing now simply won't work, nothing can possibly get routed via eth2. There are 2 ways of using 2 network cards in the same network:

- Routing
- Interface bonding

Routing is easiest: leave the default route in place and add specific routes via eth2 for hosts you want to reach via it. Bonding is more flexible but requires setup on both the server and the switch.

Comment: Depending on the bonding [*mode*](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/bonding.txt) chosen, switch support might be unnecessary.